# Strange greyness over message that was deleted during editing

Tags: bug, chat

I have recently noticed that in chat if I post a message, then click on the button to edit it, and then before finishing the edit (that is not clicking cancel nor to put the edit), delete it, it says `(removed)` and then becomes no matter what I do:

[image]